# \refstepcounter vs. \phantomsection

Tags: links, hyperlink

What's the difference between `\refstepcounter{}` and `\phantomsection` in anchoring at specific locations?

I apologize if I am mistaken but as far as I know they are both used in setting anchors to make hyperlinks link correctly when they sometimes don't link properly so I was wondering when I should use one or the other.

I already tried looking and searching everywhere (sorry if this is a duplicate question) but I have yet to find a comprehensive answer that explains and differentiates the two commands and when they should be used.

As an example, I want to create a new chapter macro that basically goes like this:

```
\newcommand{\newchapter}[1]{%
    \singlespacing
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \chapter*{#1}
    \label{chap:#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \endgroup
    \doublespacing
}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\newchapter}[1]{%
    \singlespacing
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \phantomsection
    \chapter*{#1}
    \label{chap:#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \endgroup
    \doublespacing
}
```

They both seemingly appear to have the same result and they both link properly to each chapter whenever the macro `\newchapter` is called.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `\refstepcounter` and `\phantomsection` do

```
\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}
```

which sets an anchor. The latter is simpler, because it doesn't involve raising (or lowering) the anchor and so is good to be issued in vertical mode.

Comment: Ah I see, can you please elaborate on what raising/lowering the anchor means?

Comment: @FarrelAhmed When the anchor is needed in an equation, for instance, it is raised so that the whole equation is shown at a click on the hyperlink. The amount of raising or lowering depends on the context, but for `\phantomsection` it's not needed.